# ffmpeg intensity histogram adjustment

Tags: video, image-processing, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for background correction of a video and I would like to improve the intensity scaling of the output.

My gray scale videos have dark moving objects on a light background. In 8 bit pixel intensities, the light background has pixel values around 240, the dark objects have intensities of around 120.

outside of ffmpeg, I generate a background image by taking the median frame over some number of frames.
Then, I use ffmpeg to blend/divide each frame by the background image. (I want to use division, not subtraction of the background).
[there is also some cropping in my ffmpeg command, but it is irrelevant to my question]

`'ffmpeg.exe', '-i', u'inputVideo.avi', '-i', u'bgMed.tif', '-y', '-r', '160', '-filter_complex', "[1:0] setsar=sar=1 [1sared]; [0:0][1sared] blend=all_mode='divide':repeatlast=1,format=gray,split=1 [int1];[int1]crop=1097:1097:12:11:[out1]", '-map', '[out1]', '-c:v', 'libxvid', '-q:v', '5', '-g', '10', u'outputVideo'`

This procedure is basically working but the resulting video frames look too washed out. This is probably expected? I am guessing ffmpeg does the division and produces an internal float result which it then maps back to an 8 bit output. I would like to stretch the histogram of the result from the division. It would be preferable to stretch before the mapping to 8 bit for a finer dynamic range.

In my example, I am assuming that the background division produces a result frame that has a value close to 1 for the background, and values close to 0.5 for the dark objects. Then, ffmpeg seems to be mapping the full range 0-1 into 8 bit 0-255. I would like it to map the range 0.5-1 of the division result into the 8 bit range of the output. is this possible somehow? Or how else can I achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 0):

the filter lutyuv can do that:
it can be used to apply a transformation function on just luminance

`lutyuv=y=(val-min_intensity)*(maxval/(maxval-min_intensity))`

apply this filter to the output or both of the inputs. This requires coming up with a good value for min_intensity. If applied to the output, min_intensity should be the minimum intensity value of the output.